# Converting the variable to listenable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a value that undergoes the changes ([SlidingPanel position](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_panel#-readme-tab-)). Unfortunately creator of this plug-in didn't make the controller of this panel listenable, but he added the onPanelSlide function using which I fetch the current position of the panel. I have the double, but don't have  the listener, that's why I have to implement my own listenable to create the AnimatedBuilder. How can I convert double varying from 0.0 to 1.0 to `listenable, so I can plug it's value to AnimatedBuilder's animation parameter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it work to just convert it to a stream? I've never done this with animations, but you could maybe do something like this:

```
StreamController<double> _animationController = StreamController<double>.broadcast();
Function get updateAnimation => _animationController.sink.add;
Stream get animationStream => _animationController.stream;
```

If you pass the updateAnimation function directly to onPanelSlide, you should be able to listen to those values in the animationStream.

Comment: Thank you, but when I try to initialize the _animationController it returns something like - Close instances of `dart.core.Sink`. Do you have any Idea what is it about?

Comment: that is a warning to prevent memory leaks, if you have a bunch of stream controllers and never closed them that would be bad for performance. typically you would include a dispose method that called _animationController.close(), or call it from the stateful widget's dispose() method, or put the stream in a separate class and used the Provider package, which includes a dispose method.

Comment: Sorry @Kris for my stupidity, but while we're at it, my app returns the error "Bad state, stream has already been listened to", I've made the StreamBuilder and put the stream in there, but something's wrong.

Comment: No worries. A stream, by itself, is a simple object that can only be listened to by one thing, so that is an error that happens if the stream is listened to multiple times. If that is unavoidable you can either instantiate the stream controller as a broadcast stream controller by using StreamController.broadcast() or do like I do and just use rxdart and the BehaviorSubject class, which works just like a StreamController but it can be listened to multiple times ... but I've never done this with animations before so I'm not sure if this is the correct approach here.

Comment: yees! After some time I finally got it to work. StreamController<double>.broadcast() was what I needed, as far as my understanding goes. Thank you. I will be hoping that it's the best possible solution

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it! Updated the answer accordingly.